# got memoryerror creating ODM=np.zeros((n,n)) with iterating

Tags: python, numpy, out-of-memory

```
  import networkx as nx
  import matplotlib
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import matplotlib.cm as cm
  import gc
  import numpy as np
  from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
  from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
  import pandas as pd
  from sklearn import preprocessing
  #some modules are unused

df_raw = pd.read_csv("AllUserTraj.csv", sep='\t')
df_raw = df_raw.drop('Unnamed: 0', 1) # You may start from df_raw
df = df_raw[['Latitude','Longitude','UserID','Domestic','Weekday','WaitingTime','DayHour']]
```

## df:contain:'Latitude','Longitude','UserID','Domestic' 0 or 1,'Weekday' 0 or 1,'WaitingTime' in minute,'DayHour' from 1 to 24

```
def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2): 
"""
Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
on the earth (specified in decimal degrees) in km
"""
# convert decimal degrees to radians 
lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

# haversine formula 
dlon = lon2 - lon1 
dlat = lat2 - lat1 
a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
return c * r

def ODM_cal(df_user, ID):
    aggregate_features = pd.DataFrame()
    p = df_user.groupby(['Latitude','Longitude'])['UserID'].count()
    n = len(p)
    aggregate_features = pd.DataFrame(p)
    aggregate_features['temp'] = aggregate_features.index
    lat = list()
    long = list()
    for index, row in aggregate_features.iterrows():
        lat.append(row['temp'][0])
        long.append(row['temp'][1])
    aggregate_features['Latitude'] = lat
    aggregate_features['Longitude'] = long
    aggregate_features = aggregate_features.drop('temp', 1)
    aggregate_features = aggregate_features.sort_values('UserID', ascending=False)
    aggregate_features = aggregate_features.reset_index(drop=True)

    ODM = np.zeros((n,n))
    frequency = dict()
    count = 0
    for index, row in df_user.iterrows():
    Latitude = row['Latitude']
    Longitude = row['Longitude']
    location_index = aggregate_features[(aggregate_features['Latitude'] == Latitude) & (aggregate_features['Longitude'] == Longitude)].index.tolist()[0]
    if count == 0:
        destination_index = location_index
    else:
        origin_index = destination_index
        destination_index = location_index
        if destination_index != origin_index:
            ODM[origin_index, destination_index] += 1 #Count trip number
        if location_index not in frequency:
            frequency[location_index] = 0
        frequency[location_index] += 1
    count+= 1
## Calculate distance matrix
    DistanceM = np.zeros((n,n))
    for i in range(0,n):
        for j in range(i,n):
            DistanceM[i, j] = haversine(aggregate_features['Longitude'][i], aggregate_features['Latitude'][i], aggregate_features['Longitude'][j], aggregate_features['Latitude'][j])
            return (aggregate_features, frequency, ODM, DistanceM)
```

I created a matrix with np.zeros. But while running the memoryerror happened like:

"ODM = np.zeros((n,n))
    MemoryError"

I wanna ask:
(1)what problems actually ?
(2)how to avoid?

i run it with python3.6 (64bits) numpy (64bits)
i believe the environment is not the problem.

probably the iterating demand too much memory?
how to optimize? with gc.？

df is a dataframe collected from csv file,contain some space time info.

show me the details,thanks!

Comment: Clearly  `n` is too big,  since the error arise at the first line.

Comment: the size of dataframe i analyze is (1671108，7) , is it too big?Should I Split the dataframe to parts？ then how ?

Comment: Difficult to understand. what are df_user. shape, n ,aggregate_feature.shape and what they contains.

Comment: the code is rewrote and the entire code is showed ,hope it makes sense. these are used to calculate ODM matrix (analyze  temporal-spatial traits)

Comment: so `n=1671108`,  and ODM is 2 tera octets large. you can't put it  in memory. Ask you which of this distance  are really necessary.

Comment: i wanna collect all the distance result, any methods?thanks

Comment: maybe i should split the dataframe and  calculate one user by one user?